# How do I find a list of healthy nodes in a TCP haproxy setup

Tags: haproxy

I have an haproxy setup which is NOT fronting an HTTP cluster. How can I ask haproxy which nodes are currently in the healthy list, and which are considered unhealthy?

I found the "stats" command, but that only works for HTTP traffic

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional port to your frontend (e.g. 8080) and enable stats for only that backend.

```
frontend
    bind *:123,*:8080

    acl is_stats dst_port 8080
    use_backend stats if is_stats

    default_backend your_TCP_backend

backend stats
    stats enable
```